# Liquid check if metafield exists

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shopify, liquid

I want to check if a metafield (created with metafields Guru) exists on a product or not and based on that change a variable to show or hide the div holding the metafield.

I got this:

```
{% assign display = "inline-block" %}

{% if product.metafields.energielabel.energie.value  == blank %}
{% assign display = "none" %}
{% endif %}

<div id="energielabel-container"><img class="label" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0619/8034/4516/{{ product.metafields.energielabel.energie.value }}" /></div>


<style>
#energielabel-container {
width: 80px;
display: {{ display }};
}


</style>
```

When I just add some example letters into to the if condition it´s working as it should (empty metafield = shows the exaple letters ), but redefining the variable doesn´t work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img class="label" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0619/8034/4516/{{product.metafields.energielabel.energie.value}}" />
```

The line above is questionable. you should store the whole url instead;

using your method will create extra code and errors; the `img` tag will still fetch the url that does not exist.  So just check with `if` tag and put all code inside.

```
{% if product.metafields.energielabel.energie.value %}

<style>
#energielabel-container {
width: 80px;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div id="energielabel-container">
    <img class="label" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0619/8034/4516/{{product.metafields.energielabel.energie.value}}" />
</div>


{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement checks if metafield is blank using `==` operator. What you want is to check if it's **not** blank (if it exists)

Try:

```
{% if product.metafields.energielabel.energie.value != blank %}
  {% assign display = "none" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Comment: @SaeedZhiany done, however the change, in this case, is so small I didn't think the additional description is needed.